# Setting the same keys in an array of an object of objects

Tags: javascript, function, api, key, javascript-objects

I'm trying to accomplish what initially seemed like a simple task, but is starting to prove to be somewhat difficult for me. I have an object being sent from the client, to a serverless function. It's of variable length based on the fields filled out on a form.

For example - below is an object I've received from the client. 2 form field groups have been filled out in this case, that I've encased in an array in an attempt to make it easier to work with. It also just so happens that I need it to be this way to satisfy the final step of my process, which is to send this data from my serverless function to an API endpoint via POST request.

I need to change all of the objects named "itemInfo(x)" into "properties" to fulfill the API requirements. I've tried quite a few different solutions to no avail.

If someone could offer some help/insight, I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
[
  {
    itemInfo0: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'POWER - NONE W/ ANY SOURCE',
      serial_number: 'testserial123',
      part_number: '1170-3441 (OxyGo NEXT Slim Backpack)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
    },
    itemInfo1: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'REPLACE COLUMNS',
      serial_number: '123',
      part_number: '1170-3410 (OxyGo NEXT Carry Bag)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
    }
  }
]
```

I have to turn the above into into:

```
inputs: [
      {
        **properties**: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'POWER - NONE W/ ANY SOURCE',
      serial_number: 'testserial123',
      part_number: '1170-3441 (OxyGo NEXT Slim Backpack)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
        }
      },
      {
        **properties**: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'REPLACE COLUMNS',
      serial_number: '123',
      part_number: '1170-3410 (OxyGo NEXT Carry Bag)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting as the output.... what is the `**properties**:` supposed to mean? So it is supposed to be changed to individual objects in an array? What did you attempt?

Comment: @epascarello - you're right. It is a bit unclear. The "properties" was to highlight what I need changed. I should have just labelled the lower code block as "output". Apologies!

What I have now is an array that encases an object, with a variable amount of objects inside that object. I need to turn this into an array, filled with a variable amount of objects, each encasing another single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way ?

```
const inputs = Object.values(data[0]).map(el => ({properties : el}))
```

demo:

```js
const data = 
  [ { itemInfo0: 
      { initial_repair_reason : 'POWER - NONE W/ ANY SOURCE'
      , serial_number         : 'testserial123'
      , part_number           : '1170-3441 (OxyGo NEXT Slim Backpack)'
      , hs_pipeline           : '8360749'
      , hs_pipeline_stage     : '8360750'
      , hubspot_owner_id      : '910901'
      , subject               : 'Repair Request'
      } 
    , itemInfo1: 
      { initial_repair_reason : 'REPLACE COLUMNS'
      , serial_number         : '123'
      , part_number           : '1170-3410 (OxyGo NEXT Carry Bag)'
      , hs_pipeline           : '8360749'
      , hs_pipeline_stage     : '8360750'
      , hubspot_owner_id      : '910901'
      , subject               : 'Repair Request'
      } 
    } 
  ] 

const inputs = Object.values(data[0]).map(el => ({properties : el}))

console.log( inputs )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: You are a beautiful human being and I am eternally grateful. Thank you so very much!

Comment: relatively new to posting on here. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array and then loop over the Object.values() of each object to create  new ones with the `properties` key

```js
const res = data.reduce((a,o) =>{
  Object.values(o).forEach(v => a.push({properties: v}))
  return a;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

```html
<script>
const data =[
  {
    itemInfo0: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'POWER - NONE W/ ANY SOURCE',
      serial_number: 'testserial123',
      part_number: '1170-3441 (OxyGo NEXT Slim Backpack)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
    },
    itemInfo1: {
      initial_repair_reason: 'REPLACE COLUMNS',
      serial_number: '123',
      part_number: '1170-3410 (OxyGo NEXT Carry Bag)',
      hs_pipeline: '8360749',
      hs_pipeline_stage: '8360750',
      hubspot_owner_id: '910901',
      subject: 'Repair Request'
    }
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: You are also an incredibly beautiful human being and I am also eternally grateful for your help. Thank you!